# OpsMgr 2012 agent installation fails with "One or more computers you are trying to manage are already in the process of being managed"

Tags: windows-server-2012, scom, system-center, management-pack

I am authoring a management pack in XML and using the authoring console in System Center. For testing the MP I created, I need to install agents on machines that have my distributed app running.

SCOM Operations Manager 2012 agent installation fails with

> One or more computers you are trying to manage are already in the process of being managed

I know this issue should be resolved from the database - do you know what SQL queries I should run to remove the machines I am trying to install agents on from the pending actions table?

Comment: I truly think this question is relevant. I have edited it to show that I am authoring a management pack which is technically software development. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Procedure here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/operationsmgr/archive/2010/05/26/opsmgr-2007-agent-installation-fails-with-quot-one-or-more-computers-you-are-trying-to-manage-are-already-in-the-process-of-being-managed-quot.aspx)

1. Back up the database!
2. Execute the following query:

```
SELECT AgentPendingActionId
FROM AgentPendingAction
WHERE AgentName like 'computername'
```

This should output any single entry that points to the same agent.

1. Run the command below remove the agent from pending Management:

```
DECLARE @ActionId uniqueidentifier
SET @ActionId =
(
   SELECT AgentPendingActionId
   FROM AgentPendingAction
   WHERE AgentName like 'computername'
)
EXEC p_AgentPendingActionDeleteByIdList @AgentPendingActionIdList = @ActionId
```

Once you complete this, you should be able to re-run agent discovery and successfully install the agent.